# Php - Is it possible to block access to a webpage depending on the address used?

Tags: php, access-control

Consider the following scenario.

There is a site on a local network which can be accessed one of 2 ways:

1. 11.11.11.111/testsite (ip)
2. test.site.com (vhost)

Is it possible with php to only allow access using test.site.com?

EDIT:

While there were many good suggestions as to how to solve this problem, I went with Publi Design & John V.'s mod_rewrite suggestion, but I implemented it in the httpd.conf file and redirected to a forbidden page.

What worked for me was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

Comment: You would be much better of enforcing this requirement at the web-server level. That way you can only allow certain IP's to access the development site and not have to write any code to enforce it.

Comment: @MichaelP Thats a good point but the only problem is there are different people that need access at different times so it would mean a lot of chopping and changing etc. But you are probably correct to say it is the right way to do it! Maybe I'm just being lazy!

Comment: You could use `mod_rewrite` to force them too `test.site.com`

Comment: @doovers If you're having to constantly change the rules, wouldn't maintaining a .htaccess file be far simpler then maintaining a block of code that would need to be removed once the site is deployed.

Comment: @MichaelP That makes sense actually but what would be the easiest way to get the ip addresses from users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the PHP request and go up one level. I haven't tried this, but maybe the `.htaccess` file could help you, using something similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^11.11.11.111/testsite$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You might have to play around with it, but I would imagine something along those lines should get you to where you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael P suggested in his comment, it's best to do this using a server configuration file, rather than with PHP. But it **is** possible with PHP, and rather easy. All you need is a simple `if/else` statement using PHP's global variable `$_SERVER`. Something like this should do.

```
<?php
// put this at the top of every page that will be accessed
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'test.test.com') { 'Please visit this site using the correct link: http://test.test.com'; exit; }
?>
```